# how can i make 'last -n' return just the n lines of users?

Tags: awk, last

I wrote this simple awk program:

```
last -n 10 | awk'{print "username: " $1}'
```

I was surprised when i got the following output:

```
> username: someUsername1
> username: someUsername2
> username: someUsername3
> ...
> username: someUsername10
> username: 
> username: wtmp
```

using `last -n 10 | wc -l` i learned that the `last` command return two more lines than the number i gave it (the output was `12`)

I checked in `man last` and didn't find anything about those two extra lines or how to get rid of them.

what are those blank and 'wtmp' lines? and how can i ignore them?
(maybe in the side of the awk?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution which will work everywhere, and when there are fewer than ten entries in the login database, is to trim the last two lines:

```
last -n 10 | head -n -2 | awk'{print "username: " $1}'
```

Recent versions of `util-linux` (2.30.2 and later) allow the `wtmp` line to be dropped:

```
last -n 10 --time-format=notime | awk'{print "username: " $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run last without any arguments, I get the following output:

```
wtmp begins Fri Sep 22 18:15:02 2017
```

And an empty line before it. This is the date from which the logins are recorded.

You can get rid of this using head.

```
last | head -n10
```

Comment: In fact, you may drop all options to `last` as you're limiting the number of lines with `head` anyway. Also, 10 lines is the default for `head` (and `tail`).

Comment: Good point. Will edit my answer to include this.

Comment: This fails when there are fewer than ten entries in `wtmp`.

Comment: thanks! but Stephan solution is cover all cases